# Start the IntegrationTest by calling REST endpoint in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, microservices, integration-testing

I am assuming this is possible and is not against standards / Bad Practice.

We are writing end to end tests in SpringBoot `@SpringBootTest` for Micro Services and this end to end tests are in a separate module / project (like a microservice).

Plan is to write a controller with an endpoint and takes a profile as param, to run the test `@SpringBootTest` programmatically.

Questions:

1. How do we run the test the in the way specified above.
2. Should we still keep the tests in `src/test` instead of `src/main`, since in the end to end spring boot application, all that it has is just a Test class (`@SpringBootTest`) with some helper classes?
3. Any other better ways/approaches/standards to organize this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
Why though? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Question #1: Please see example test below.

Question #2: Best practice is to keep tests in src/test.

Question #3: No, I think you're good to go.

**TestRestTemplate vs. WebTestClient**

> NOTE: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor
> requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please,
> consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient
> which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming
> scenarios.
>
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Creating a Multi Module Project: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.user;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class LoginControllerTest {

    private static final String API_1_0_LOGIN = "/api/1.0/login";

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void cleanup(){
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void postLogin_withoutUserCredentials_receiveUnauthorized() {
        webTestClient.post()
                .uri(API_1_0_LOGIN)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isUnauthorized();
    }

    ...
}
```

Please note that you'll need this dependency for `WebTestClient`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The above example is how to test the controller / call controller endpoint. But I want to be able to start the tests from a controller. However, the tests @SpringBootTest class is sitting in `/src/test`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I prefer the cucumber test solution for the end-to-end test.

So answer your questions in Cucumber's way:

1. This is [a simple example](https://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-spring-integration) about how to implement and trigger the tests.
2. Create a separate module, if we want to reuse the steps definition, move the steps to separate project.
3. I think Cucumber is a better solution as the end-to-end test.

**More details:**

We can create a separate project to define the reusable steps, then create a separate module in the API project to store the features, and add the step definition project as the dependency.

The benefits we got from cucumber solution is the simple syntax of Gherkin, make  writing and maintenance of the test very efficient, even our BA can write the test after reading several example. And we are very happy with the performance so far.

The following list is the dependencies we used for the cucumber steps definition project:

- io.cucumber:cucumber-java
- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit (use junit to trigger features)
- io.cucumber:cucumber-spring (so we can use spring context. e.g. ContextConfiguration)
- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path (the [jsonpath](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) is handy to access specific result you want)

Comment: Though, I like Cucumber tests, team is not skilled/comfortable enough to use it.